# Msql select sum limit ignore

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a situation where i need to avoid repetitive numbers within the query itself.

i have a code like this:

```
    $rangelimit     = range(6, 60, 6);
    $name            = "some name";
    foreach( $rangelimit as $limit){

       $result = $db->query("SELECT SUM(numbers) 
                  FROM (SELECT numbers FROM table WHERE name ='".$name."' 
                  ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,".$limit.") 
                  AS SUBT");

        if($result)
            echo $limit.' value is .' $result;

    }// end foreach

    // outputs
    // 6 value is 22
    // 12 value is 32
    // 18 value is 40
    // but here is the problem once there is no more results 
    // i want it to stop and give 0
    // 24 value is 40
    // 30 value is 40 ... and keeps going on till 60 as set on the range.
```

My question is query related as i can stop it within foreach loop but i want to know if there is any way that you can tell the query to stop if there is no result up-to the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the sum to be 0 where there are not enough rows in the for the limit.  Here is a method:

```
SELECT (case when count(*) = ".$limit."
             then SUM(numbers) 
             else 0
        end)
FROM (SELECT numbers
      FROM table
      WHERE name ='".$name."' 
      ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,".$limit."
     ) SUBT;
```

Comment: what if there are rows but not upto the limit can we use something like greater or smaller?
count(*) > or < ".$limit."?

Comment: @Genus . . . Ironically, I first wrote the query that way.  But, because of the limit, either the number will equal the limit or the value should be 0.